# UISearchbar height and width issue

Tags: ios

I have implemented UISearchbar in UISearchController which is placed inside a UIView. But the searchbar doesn't fit correctly in iPad..In iPhone , it works correctly by setting sizeToFit and the frame.size.width as per the stack overflow answers. Please help me to work with iPad also.
I followed the answer in this link - [Display UISearchController's searchbar programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31283523/display-uisearchcontrollers-searchbar-programmatically)

```
var pickUpresultsViewController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController?
var pickUpSearchController: UISearchController?

pickUpresultsViewController = GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController()
pickUpresultsViewController?.delegate = self

pickUpSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: pickUpresultsViewController)
pickUpSearchController?.searchResultsUpdater = pickUpresultsViewController

pickUpSearchController?.searchBar.placeholder = "From:"
pickUpView.addSubview((pickUpSearchController?.searchBar)!)
pickUpSearchController?.searchBar.sizeToFit()
// For some reason, the search bar will extend outside the view to the left after calling sizeToFit. This next line corrects this.
pickUpSearchController?.searchBar.frame.size.width = pickUpView.frame.size.width

definesPresentationContext = true
pickUpSearchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
```

Comment: Add your code work or screen shot images and mention which stack overflow answer you are following.\